# Reordering boxplots by median across facets .. on a 'per-facet' basis

Tags: r, ggplot2

When faceting a plot, the reordering is determined by the entire dataset, not on a 'per-facet' basis.

Here is a very simple minimal example:

```
diamonds %>% 
  filter(cut=="Ideal" | cut=="Premium") %>% 
  filter(clarity=="VVS1" | clarity=="SI1") %>% 
ggplot(., aes(x=reorder(color, price, FUN = median), y=price)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_wrap(~clarity, scales="free")
```

The expected result was a plot with two facets and with the boxplots ordered by median value within each facet. That is not the case :

[image]

Now, if we remove the faceting, the resulting plot looks as expected:

```
diamonds %>% 
  filter(cut=="Ideal" | cut=="Premium") %>% 
  filter(clarity=="VVS1" | clarity=="SI1") %>% 
ggplot(., aes(x=reorder(color, price, FUN = median), y=price)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

You'll notice that the order of 'color' is the same in all three plots which lead me to conclude, that the order is determined by the entire data set, and that order is retained in the two separate facets.

What we really wanted was the 'color' ordered per facet. How to accomplish this ... and more importantly, what is the underlying principle I have failed to grasp which that leads me to expect something other than what Hadley had in mind?

P.S 
I know that ggplot2 respects the ordering of the data and that 'on principle' the order should be dictated by the data and not the plot-call, thus the proper way is to sort data prior to plotting by manipulating the data beforehand. There are several Q&A's here and elsewhere that show how this can be done.

However, there is also a case for using reorder within the ggplot command -- e.g. when using a summary function such as 'median', whilst preserving the raw data for the ggplot function call.

This post has been flagged as a duplicate -- it is not as far as I can tell. The central issue here is not ordering boxplots as such, but how to ensure that this is done of a per-facet basis and not across-facets.

Comment: I would probably create a new column as a factor with levels in the right order, and then re-set the labels manually with `scale_x_discrete`. It's probably a bit unsatisfying, but seems like it's probably the tidyverse-certified solution.

Comment: I dont believe this is a duplicate of previous questions ... The central issue here is how to avoid that sorting of data is done as a whole rather than per facet. As I hinted, I know it can be achieved by manipulating the data before hand, but it would be more" satisfactory" to do it without such shenanigans.